# Objet supprimé avec un verbe transitif

Tags: grammaire, verbes, compléments

Regardez ce vers d'une chanson :

> Pour tout le mal qu'on s'est pas dit
>
> Certains rigolent déjà
>
> J' m'en fous, j' les aimais pas
>
> On avait l'air trop bien
>
> **Y en a qui n' supportent pas**

Mais *supporter* est un verbe transitif. Je m’attendais un objet : *Y en a qui n' supportent pas ça*. Où est passé le *ça* ?

Une autre fois j'ai entendue quelqu'un dire « J'adore ! » par lequel elle voulait dire « J'adore ça ! » Encore, où est passé le *ça* ?

Quelle est la règle ? Est-ce qu'on peut toujours enlever le *ça* ?

Comment: Tout ça me dépasse la tête trop pour en faire une réponse, mais [cet article](https://praxematique.revues.org/2999) parle des notions de «l’emploi absolu» et «l’anaphore ø/anaphorique zéro» pour expliquer  l’usage de quelques verbes transitifs sans COD. Le mot «supporter» ne figure pas du tout dans l’article, mais  «Note 9» mentionne «accepter» et d’après [*CNRTL-TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/supporter), «supporter», en emploi absolu, peut dire «accepter».

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalement, on devrait toujours ajouter un COD aux verbes transitifs.

Toutefois, on observe un usage sans COD, pour certains verbes très courants, surtout d'**appréciation**:

- tu aimes les pommes ? j'aime (ou je n'aime pas).
- je déteste, j'apprécie, j'adore.
- je ne supporte pas. (*je supporte* est plus rare).
- je pense, je ne pense pas.
- je comprends.
- ...

Comment: « C'était comment les vacances ? » — « J'ai adoré. »

Comment: @LukeSawczak - merci , ajouté à la liste.

Answer (score 4):

En chanson, et en poésie, on peut quand même se permettre des tournures qui ne seraient normalement pas acceptables à l'écrit.

Dans une conversation, je pense pas qu'il soit particulièrement rare d'élider le complément d'objet direct, surtout quand il est clair en contexte.

Ici, je pense que Patrick Bruel a tout simplement évité de dire soit "ne le supportent pas" ou "ne supportent pas ça" parce que ça n'allait pas avec la mélodie de sa chanson.

Je ne suis pas certain qu'il y ait de règle ferme avec laquelle on puisse définir ce phénomène linguistique, mais je pense qu'un "*ça*" en fin de phrase, comme ici, peut souvent être abrégé quand le complément d'objet direct qu'il remplace vient tout just d'être mentionné.